# Implement Play Store like animation in SearchWidget

Tags: android, android-animation, material-design

I would like to add an animation to my application which does the same as the Play Store:

[image: before animation]

[image: after animation]

The search widget grows from the right to fill the whole ToolBar. I use the Search Widget explained [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html).
I didn't really find a solution so far. Maybe someone has more experience and can help me out. Thanks...

Answer (score 2):

I have put together a sample of how to create the search bar and a couple of other toolbar examples.  it is under FloatingSearchToolbar file.  You would need to have the view over the main toolbar and set the floating toolbar to be View.GONE.

https://github.com/EugeneHoran/Android-Hard-Toolbar-with-many-different-elements

As for the animation you would need to configure a view animation from the top right corner. The view animation below is from a sample from google which could be found on.

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-RevealEffectBasic/

```
 Animator animator = ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(
                View v **Your view here**,
                0,
                0,
                0,
                (float) Math.hypot(shape.getWidth(), shape.getHeight()));
```